# How would i go about editing a specific h4 tag without affecting others

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok guys this is a Re-Upload since I poorly explained which I would like to apologize for. (I deleted the old post)

I am looking to edit

```
<div id="viewer_viewer_container" style="display: block;">
    <h4>original-content i want to edit</h4>
    <ul id="viewer_viewer_list" class="viewer_list"></ul>
</div>
```

I want the text in the header `<h4>original-content i want to edit</h4>` to change value depending on the URL.

For instance, if the URL is `http://www.site.com/chat/embed/channel-name` I would need code along the lines of `if (loc.indexOf( "http://www.site.com/chat/embed/channel-name") != - 1)`

But on that note since I'm making a change to it anyway I would also like to add my own default edit on top of the specific request.

For example:

```
if (loc.indexOf( "http://www.site.com/chat/embed/channel-name") != - 1) {
    specific edit
}
else {
    original edit
}
```

Also, can you please refrain from putting it on hold if it is not setup correctly? I will work with you to edit it to a much more specific understanding.

Comment: What do you mean by this: " I also want it so it edits http://www.site.com/chat/embed/channel-name" ?

Comment: a specific change of a specific chat embed within the site i'm modifying 3rd party `if (loc.indexOf( "http://www.site.com/chat/embed/channel-name") != - 1) {`

Comment: What i am looking for is a way to edit that tag and an alternative to the php else change

Comment: Ok, I don't see a tag with that url in your example code. And I know you don't want to edit that url as a string. Please show the code that uses that url.

Comment: no no no i want to edit `<div id="viewer_viewer_container" style="display: block;">
    <h4>original-content i want to edit</h4>
    <ul id="viewer_viewer_list" class="viewer_list"></ul>
</div>` `<h4>original-content i want to edit</h4>` but specific changes to certain urls

Comment: basically like a php alternative to the else if script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the `<h4>` tag an id and call it with jquery and use the `.html()` method like so:

```
<h4 id="change-me">Original Text</h4>
```

and the javascript:

```
if (loc.indexOf( "http://www.site.com/chat/embed/channel-name") != - 1) {
    $("#change-me").html('Edited Value');
}
else {
    //leave as is
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is about the text of the h4 element, then try this:

```
var toEdit = $('h4').text();
/* select the h4 with the text provided */
if(toEdit == 'original-content i want to edit') {
   toEdit.text('set new text here...');
}
```

Then edit the text and update it!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/30sd6h this is a poor example of what i mean (i know its incorrectly formatted i rushed it for an example